# Why does clearing cookies fix a 408?

Tags: firefox, debian, timeout

I am running firefox out of a debian vm, and get a lot of 408s back. Googling has told me that clearing cookies would fix that problem, and it does, but only until those cookies get set again.

Does anybody know why clearing cookies would fix that problem? I assume I have a networking issue, but am baffled as to why clearing cookies would affect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a browser makes an HTTP Request to a web-server for a document, that request contains any [cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) you had for that [context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) (usually site) so that the server can perform any actions required based on values it expects in the cookie(s).

Your request is broken up and sent to the server in as many packets as are necessary, so the HTTP request itself is treated as a stream. once that stream starts coming in, a timer is set, and if the stream doesn't contain the end of the request by the time the timer goes off, the server decides that the request has "Timed Out". this is important, because if the server didn't make this choice, it would be trivial to DOS a site by sending the begining of a request stream many many times, without ever finishing one, and will fill up the servers capacity to hold pending requests, at which point new requests could not connect at all. Instead the server just returns a [408](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html). 408's can reflect server issues, but if clearing cookies works, and the issue affects many sites/servers, than its likely the issue is on your end.

Based on your description, either:

1. the cookie is enormous and takes a long time/bandwidth to send,
2. too many cookies fit the context (lots of 3rd party cookies like
   doubleclick et al), and take too long to send all of them,
3. or your system is taking too long to read and stream the cookie,
   perhaps do to network problems, disk problems, or other operational
   issues.

by Clearing your cookies, you can address all three of these concerns, because you don't have a cookie to send, or the cookie now contains only minimal data, or because third party cookies that would otherwise have been sent are now gone, and only the sites cookie remains.